# Magento 2: The value of the "Manufacturer" attribute isn't unique. Set a unique value and try again

Tags: magento2.3.2, manufacturer

I have imported products in magento.

After I am going to update one product It gives me this error.

There is manufacturer empty.But existing products with empty manufacturer after updating without manufacturer it saves.

But only new product not saving, it gives me above error.

```
 The value of the "Manufacturer" attribute isn't unique. Set a unique
 value and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 can not allow add duplicate Values of  Attribute.

The Unique value option is to control the attribute to be shared / not across other products.

***Unique Value***

Requires the attribute value to be different from all other values entered in the same attribute, within the context of the scope setting.

Unique value should be enabled for any attribute that is used as an ID number.

For example, because SKU is used to identify products throughout the hierarchy, it has a unique value with a global scope. Options: Yes / No

[image]

Check the attributes listed in the error are not repeated in your attribute value.

Comment: i kept this value is empty...and existing product have empty manufacturer field..On update it showing no error..Only new products are showing this error